# Change the Unity launcher search provider

Tags: unity, launcher, search

If I enter a term that gives no hits in Applications etc. I will automatically redirected to the Yahoo search page.

How can I change the search provider there?

I found out, that the content-search is enabled in the settings:

```
gsettings list-recursively |grep remote-content-search
```

This will show

```
com.canonical.Unity.Lenses remote-content-search 'all'
```

Is this related? Or where can I set the automated search to another provider?

Comment: That's.. weird. The dash will actually call your browser and open a Yahoo! search? I can't get mine to do anything like that for the life of me. What search terms did you use?

Comment: I didn't try it ever since, cause I didn't want to search with Yahoo. But now I cannot get this behaviour either any more. Maybe some updates solved this problem. I will post that as answer, thanks for looking into this ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try it ever since, cause I didn't want to search with Yahoo. But now I cannot get this behaviour either any more. Maybe some updates solved this problem.

So the solution seems to be **Update your system with**:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudi apt-get upgrade
```